# "‘return’ with a value, in function returning void" when returning a struct

Tags: c, struct, typedef

I am getting compilation error:

```
warning: ‘return’ with a value, in function returning void
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
  int a;
  char b;
}
values;

values keyword;

struct values get_keyword(void)
{
  return keyword;
}

int main()
{
   keyword.a = 10; 
}
```

Comment: The error you posted doesn't correspond with this code. Is this the real code? Other than that, `struct values` -> `values`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and *ask a question*. Also please try to make sure you understand the terms you are using. "I am returning a typedef function" makes no sense at all.

Comment: @Lundin yes it does (more or less):  https://godbolt.org/z/5cnMdG1hM

Comment: @Jabberwocky Why would the OP post the 2nd compiler error and not the 1st though? That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Lundin so you've never seen incomplete error logs in posts of first time SO users? ;-)

Comment: @Lundin It's just a common rookie mistake - focusing on secondary errors.

Comment: Sigh. Well this is why one should take classes where a teacher explains focus on the _first_ error... fine, I'll cast a reopen vote.

Comment: Mahesh: Did any of the answers answer your question? Please ask if you need further clarification.

Answer (score 2):

`struct values` is not a type. `values` is though, since you `typedef`ined it:

Corrected:

```
values get_keyword(void) {
    return keyword;
}
```

A more complete output from when compiling your program would include this first error:

```
<source>:10:15: error: return type is an incomplete type
   10 | struct values get_keyword(void) {
      |               ^~~~~~~~~~~
<source>: In function 'get_keyword':
```

So, now `get_keyword` becomes `void` which triggers the secondary error you showed in the question:

```
<source>:11:12: warning: 'return' with a value, in function returning void
   11 |     return keyword;
      |            ^~~~~~~
<source>:10:15: note: declared here
   10 | struct values get_keyword(void) {
      |               ^~~~~~~~~~~
ASM generation compiler returned: 1
```

Previous errors often explains later errors, which was the case here.

Comment: This doesn't explain the compiler error.

Comment: @Lundin, It does explain the compiler error in the OP's code. ("error: return type is an incomplete type" from gcc.) The error simply isn't what thet OP claims it is.

Comment: @Lundin I tried the code out now and perhaps the updated explanation is better?

Comment: @Lundin I believe that OP did not ask about explanation of the particular error, only what to do to compile this code without errors

Comment: @0___________ Because that's like I asking "why did my car crash into a hole in the ground as I was driving down the highway - I only got a warning sign speed limit 90km/h"... but failing to mention that before that they drove past the sign saying "End of the road - construction area".

Comment: @Lundin :-) Indeed. I added a note about that to the answer too.

Answer (score 1):

Your struct has no tag, only typedefed alias name `values`.

```
typedef struct
{
    int a;
    char b;
}values;

values keyword;

values get_keyword(void)
{
   return keyword;
}
```

If you want to use it without using the alias (but still to use typedef) you need to add the tag:

```
typedef struct values
{
    int a;
    char b;
}values;

values keyword;

struct values get_keyword(void)
{
    return keyword;
}
```